# Incompatible block pointer type initializing float

Tags: objective-c, block

Im not sure how to get this to work: I was thinking something to do with typedef, but I can't find much on the subject.

```
    float (^pixelsToDistance)(float, float, NSString *) = ^(float distance, float scale, NSString *conversion)
    { 
        // Code goes here        
    }
```

Im trying to return a float value from this block function.
Should I use a function instead?

Comment: what is "code goes here"? That's the important part

Comment: That was just a comment I made for myself. But @jeffamaphone helped me figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: The return type is inferred by the compiler from the returned expressions inside the block. If you are complaining that the return type is inferred to something you didn't expect, we need to see the code inside the block to see why it's inferred the way it is.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler doesn't have anything to infer from, so it assumes the block returns void, which is incompatible with the declared type of pixelsToDistance. Replacing // Code goes here with return 0.0f; should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  You want:

```
float (^pixelsToDistance)(float, float, NSString *) = ^float(float distance, float scale, NSString *conversion) { ... };
```

Note the return type after the `^` on the right hand side of the assignment operator.

As the commentator points out, you can omit the return type if it's clear to the compiler what you're returning from the block.  E.g.:

```
float (^pixelsToDistance)(float, float, NSString *) = ^(float distance, float scale, NSString *conversion) { return 0.0f };
```

Comment: The return type is almost never specified when using Blocks. It is only useful in cases where the returned expression inside the block is not obviously the desired return type, e.g. if he returns an integer literal, it's not obvious it's a float.

Comment: Regardless of whether the "almost never specified" part is true or not, without the return type, Xcode produces an error in this case if you do not include the return type.

Comment: Again, NOT TRUE, if the returned expression inside the block is of float type: `float (^pixelsToDistance)(float, float, NSString *) = ^(float distance, float scale, NSString *conversion) { return 3.14f; };`

Comment: That is a different case than what was presented.

Comment: It is EXACTLY the same, except for the "code goes here".

Comment: Sounds like you have an alternate answer you'd like to propose.